# "reserved directory found" error: any way to find out which one?

Tags: blackberry-playbook

I've got a project with quite a few JS files, directories etc. The BlackBerry .bar builder says I've got a "reserved directory" in there, and it can't build.

Is there any way to find out the filename it's got a problem with? I've renamed everything called "src". Anything else I should be aware of?

Kind of annoying the guys at RIM could not be bothered to print out the filename too...

Cheers

Garry